# Mutiple select statement

Tags: mysql

hay , i have query like this

```
   $query = "SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS `row_number`, A.* FROM (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total_transaction,  MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
        FROM `transaction_fueler`, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY total_transaction DESC, max_created_at ASC
        ) A, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;";
```

result data json from above query like this

```
 1 => {#817 ▼
+"row_number": 2.0
+"user_id": 191
+"total_transaction": 8
+"max_created_at": "2020-06-15 11:25:11"
```

}

in table transaction_fueler i have column **user_id** and **user_name**,,

i want to select user_id and user_name like this

```
  $query = "SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS `row_number`, A.* FROM (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total_transaction,  MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at,
        SELECT user_name,
        FROM `transaction_fueler`, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY total_transaction DESC, max_created_at ASC
        ) A, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;";
```

but i get errror like this

[image]

how to select user_id and user_name from query above ?

Answer (score 0):

On your second query you have two SELECT next to each others and the second one has nothing to do there. That's the reason for your error.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

In one of your SELECT statements you've not said where you're selecting from.

The format of a SELECT statement should always start with

```
SELECT _ FROM _
```

Where _ is a valid statement. In your query, you have a SELECT statement with no FROM, so it doesn't know where to look for the data.

To fix the problem, simply add this FROM statement. I can't tell you exactly how to implement this as it does depend a little on what precisely you are trying to select, but hopefully you are able to fix it with this advice.

Take a look at your first, working, statement again with this in mind and you'll see that all SELECT statements are structured in this way.

I hope this helps!